# this.$set sets data only once

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am getting difficulties to update data multiple times using this.$set(). It only works for first time and if I try one more time then nothing changes. Object gets updated with new data but changes doesn't reflect on form.

> Here is what I have done so far -

```
data () {
  return {
    days : [
      {id : 1,day : 'MONDAY'    ,status : false ,times: ['']},
      {id : 2,day : 'TUESDAY'   ,status : false ,times: ['']},
      {id : 3,day : 'WEDNESDAY' ,status : false ,times: ['']},
      {id : 4,day : 'THURSDAY'  ,status : false ,times: ['']},
      {id : 5,day : 'FRIDAY'    ,status : false ,times: ['']},
      {id : 6,day : 'SATURDAY'  ,status : false ,times: ['']},
      {id : 7,day : 'SUNDAY'    ,status : false ,times: ['']}
    ],
  }
},
methods : {
  manageSlotTime(event,parentIndex,childIndex) {
    var data = this.days[parentIndex].times;
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    {
      if(i == childIndex)
      {
        if(childIndex == 0)
        {
            data[i] = {};
            data[i].slot_id = '';
            data[i].time = event;
            data[i].slot_status = false;  
        }
        else{
          data[i].time = event;
          data[i].slot_status = false;  
        }

      }
    }    
    //Here need to set data.
    this.$set(this.days[parentIndex].times, data);   
  },
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please add info for which data are you're trying to change and which are changing for the first time?

Comment: @varit05 There is a time picker to select time(Can be multiple to store multiple time slot for a single day) for every day. If I select time first time then reflections display in time picker field but when I try second time this.days object updated time with new selected time but it doesn't reflect on time picker field in a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several weird things here.

First, you setup `times` property for each day as a non-empty array - holding an empty *string* as a single element. But then each `manageSlotTime` call either augment an existing element of that array or *replace* the first one with an *object*. That replacement seems to be the reason why you see how the first `set` call kinda works. Hint: it actually doesn't.

Second, you seem to miss the fact that this line...

```
var data = this.days[parentIndex].times
```

... doesn't create a new array. Instead it creates another *reference* to the array stored in `this.days[parentIndex].times`. Afterwards anything you do to `data` within the loop is actually modifying the array inside your state directly. That, in turn, makes call to `$set` irrelevant.

Finally, for some reasons you use `for` to access a property in array by index; it's, well, just an overcomplication. Ask yourself: if you only do some work inside that `if (i === childIndex)` check, and all that work is about accessing `data[i]`, why can't you just do `data[childIndex]` directly?

The bottom line - looks like your function can be rewritten like this:

```
manageSlotTime(event, parentIndex, childIndex) {
  var timesRef = this.days[parentIndex].times;

  var slot = childIndex === 0 ? 
     { slot_id: '' } :
     Object.assign({}, timesRef[childIndex]);
  slot.time = event;
  slot.slot_status = false;

  this.$set(timesRef, childIndex, slot);
}
```

There are few questions here (what's that special about `childIndex === 0`? how `slot_id` is assigned?), but this code essentially does the same as yours, but with less lines and proper `$set` usage.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

This most likely has to do with array Caveats. You initially assign times an array. However, vue does not detect changes to arrays.

> Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue cannot detect direct changes to an array.

If the property is an array, using the following syntax within your loop should help to overcome the problem.

```
this.$set(vm.items, indexOfItem, newValue)
```

So in your example you could use the following.

```
this.$set(this.days[parentIndex].times, i, dataObject);
```

This would look something like this.

```
if(childIndex == 0) {
    data = {};
    data.slot_id = '';
    data.time = event;
    data.slot_status = false;  
    this.$set(this.days[parentIndex].times, i, data); 
}
```